# Rxjs operator switchMap

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm new with Rxjs and write some examples for better understanding. However, the example below confuses me, why the output is 0 and 1? Can someone explain it?

```
var sources = Rx.Observable.timer(1000,1000);
var higherOrder = sources.switchMap(val => Rx.Observable.of(val).delay(1000*val));
higherOrder.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

In additon:

```
var sources = Rx.Observable.timer(1000,1000);
var higherOrder = sources.switchMap(val => Rx.Observable.of(val));
higherOrder.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

the outputs are : 0 1 2 3 4 5 ...

Comment: So what you don't understand? What output you expected?

Answer (score 3):

`switchMap` will abandon (unsubscribe) the previous emitted observable once a new one arrives. So eventually your values are delayed long enough for your timer to emit a new value creating a new Observable for your `switchMap` to subscribe to abandoning the previous one before retrieving its value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get it